# How do I make an org statistics cookie count partially completed subtasks?

Tags: org-mode

Say I have the following org file:

```
* do all my chores [0%]
1. [-] vacuuming [50%]
   1. [X] vacuum kitchen
   2. [ ] vacuum pool
** TODO shopping [33%]
*** DONE buy hot sauce
CLOSED: [2019-01-18 Fri 17:57]
*** TODO buy hot peppers
*** TODO buy hot dogs
```

The top-level headline ("do all my chores") has two children; neither is done. One is a plain list ("vacuuming") with a statistics cookie at 50%. The second is a headline ("shopping") at 33%.

I would expect the top-level statistics cookie to be at 42% (an average of 50 and 33). However, it's actually at 0% -- I assume because none of its direct subtasks has been completed. Can I make it be at 42%?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't exactly what you want, but setting the `COOKIE_DATA` property to `recursive` will count subtasks instead of just the immediate children.

```
* do all my chores [25%] [1/4]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COOKIE_DATA: recursive
  :END:
1. [-] vacuuming [50%]
   1. [X] vacuum kitchen
   2. [ ] vacuum pool
** TODO shopping [33%]
*** DONE buy hot sauce
CLOSED: [2019-01-18 Fri 17:57]
*** TODO buy hot peppers
*** TODO buy hot dogs
```

I find it to behave a little strangely when there is a mix of checkboxes and headlines.  If you convert everything to a headline you get something more understandable:

```
* do all my chores [28%] [2/7]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COOKIE_DATA: recursive
  :END:
** TODO vacuuming [50%]
*** DONE vacuum kitchen
*** TODO vacuum pool
** TODO shopping [33%]
*** DONE buy hot sauce
CLOSED: [2019-01-18 Fri 17:57]
*** TODO buy hot peppers
*** TODO buy hot dogs
```

This include the "vacuuming" and "shopping" tasks as undone, which is why you only get 28% complete.  Finally, if you remove the TODO keyword from the grouped headlines you get what you want:

```
* do all my chores [40%] [2/5]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COOKIE_DATA: recursive
  :END:
** vacuuming [50%]
*** DONE vacuum kitchen
*** TODO vacuum pool
** shopping [33%]
*** DONE buy hot sauce
CLOSED: [2019-01-18 Fri 17:57]
*** TODO buy hot peppers
*** TODO buy hot dogs
```